# How to avoid preinstalled deactivated apps to auto update

Tags: application-autoupdate

I have a Samsung tablet with Microsoft One Note and Microsoft PowerPoint preinstalled, among others. I have deactivated these, but even deactivated these apps auto update eating a lot of storage.

How to avoid that?

Comment: When you say 'Deactivated' do you mean 'Disabled'? I've never known my disabled apps to ever update, but deactivated apps could just mean 'Force Stopped', hence, they are eligible for updating. Please check the terminology matches what you intend to convey.

Comment: UI is in Spanish so I don't know the proper word in English. Maybe it's 'Disabled'. I don't mean just force stopped but truly disabled (when I disable them, all updates are deleted and factory version restored).

Comment: Are you sure you haven't done something then to enable them again? Actively, maybe not, but a System Update will drop the latest on top of the old and re-enable them; you will have to go through the disable activity again. I don't believe that there is anything else that can re-enable disabled apps.

Comment: I'm sure. They auto enable and auto update about once or twice a day.

Comment: 'once or twice a day' was a key bit of information. Nothing legitimate updates that rapidly. Microsoft doesn't even update their Windows versions that often. Something is suspicious about these apps.

Comment: They didn't update so fast before deactivation. Now, they try this often to return to "current" version. Update is not to a new, different version each time, but from factory version to day's current version.

Answer (score 0):

If they come pre-installed from your carrier and/or manufacturer, they most likely are /system apps and the only thing you can do is disable them.